# Different caption alignment on different longtable pages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, longtable, tabu

I'm using `longtabu`(longtable) for splitting a table on 2 and more pages, and i want to show different captions on pages.

This works fine, however i need the first caption to be aligned left, and the next captions aligned right.

I tried using `\captionsetup` from caption package, by putting it before `\endfirsthead` to set a different alignment for the first caption, but it changes alignments for all the pages. Any idea how i can achieve different alignments?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{|X|}
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=false}
\caption{First caption\label{tab:cap1}}\\
\hline 
\endfirsthead


\caption[]{continued}\\
\endhead

\hline 1 \\ 
\hline 2 \\ 
\hline 3 \\ 
\hline 4 \\ 
\hline 5 \\ 
\hline 6 \\ 
\hline 7 \\ 
\hline 8 \\ 
\hline 9 \\ 
\hline 10 \\ 
\hline 11 \\ 
\hline 12 \\ 
\hline 13 \\ 
\hline 14 \\ 
\hline 15 \\ 
\hline 16 \\ 
\hline 1 \\ 
\hline 2 \\ 
\hline 3 \\ 
\hline 4 \\ 
\hline 5 \\ 
\hline 6 \\ 
\hline 7 \\ 
\hline 8 \\ 
\hline 9 \\ 
\hline 10 \\ 
\hline 11 \\ 
\hline 12 \\ 
\hline 13 \\ 
\hline 14 \\ 
\hline 15 \\ 
\hline 16 \\
\hline 1 \\ 
\hline 2 \\ 
\hline 3 \\ 
\hline 4 \\ 
\hline 5 \\ 
\hline 6 \\ 
\hline 7 \\ 
\hline 8 \\ 
\hline 9 \\ 
\hline 10 \\ 
\hline 11 \\ 
\hline 12 \\ 
\hline 13 \\ 
\hline 14 \\ 
\hline 15 \\ 
\hline 16 \\

\hline 
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out our site.

Comment: I would recommend staying away from the `tabu` package.  The author has stated he is implementing a new version that is not going to be backwards compatible and most likely will have issues with other packages. You may want to use the `longtable` package instead.  I'll write a possible answer

Comment: I've used longtabu for variable width columns(which longtable seems to lack) and longtable page breaking, which seemed the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a couple of new commands that change the `captionsetup` and then pass arguments to `caption`. It is then possible to set a document-wide parameter, such as `labelfont=bf` that affects both captions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf}
\newcommand\firstcaption[1]{\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}\caption{#1}}
\newcommand\followingcaption[1]{\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,labelsep=space}\caption[]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \listoftables%
    \clearpage%
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
    \begin{longtable}[t]{l}
        \firstcaption{Summary of qualitative risk factors\label{tab:label1}}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{First Column} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \followingcaption{(Continue): Summary of proven determinants for falling}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Author} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead

        \newpage
        \bottomrule

    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So my mistake was that i should have globally set the captionsetup twice, once to display captions in what style, and afterwards to reset it. And the newcommand approach seems slick, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comments, I would really suggest to avoid the `tabu` package.

Here is a sample solution with `longtable` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{longtable}[t]{l}
    \caption{Summary of qualitative risk factors}\label{tab:label1}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{First Column} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption*{\raggedleft Table \ref{tab:label1} (Continue): Summary of proven determinants for falling  }\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Author} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

\midrule 1 \\ 
\midrule 2 \\ 
\midrule 3 \\ 
\midrule 4 \\ 
\midrule 5 \\ 
\midrule 6 \\ 
\midrule 7 \\ 
\midrule 8 \\ 
\midrule 9 \\ 
\midrule 10 \\ 
\midrule 11 \\ 
\midrule 12 \\ 
\midrule 13 \\ 
\midrule 14 \\ 
\midrule 15 \\ 
\midrule 16 \\ 
\midrule 1 \\ 
\midrule 2 \\ 
\midrule 3 \\ 
\midrule 4 \\ 
\midrule 5 \\ 
\midrule 6 \\ 
\midrule 7 \\ 
\midrule 8 \\ 
\midrule 9 \\ 
\midrule 10 \\ 
\midrule 11 \\ 
\midrule 12 \\ 
\midrule 13 \\ 
\midrule 14 \\ 
\midrule 15 \\ 
\midrule 16 \\
\midrule 1 \\ 
\midrule 2 \\ 
\midrule 3 \\ 
\midrule 4 \\ 
\midrule 5 \\ 
\midrule 6 \\ 
\midrule 7 \\ 
\midrule 8 \\ 
\midrule 9 \\ 
\midrule 10 \\ 
\midrule 11 \\ 
\midrule 12 \\ 
\midrule 13 \\ 
\midrule 14 \\ 
\midrule 15 \\ 
\midrule 16 \\


    \bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I added a couple of features I thought you might like:

1. I don't use the `tabu` package (see why [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI)).
2. I'm using the `booktabs` package to improve the horizontal lines
3. I'm not defining new commands (you could also see this as a weakness).
4. I'm using `hyperref` to be able to "jump back" to the beginning of the table

Comment: Essentially inserting \raggedleft into the caption solves the problem.

Comment: @Placinta Please see my edited answer :)